# How to show that the following 2 matrices are conjugate?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

How to show that the following 2 matrices are conjugate?

\begin{bmatrix}
z & 0 \\
0 
& z^{-1} 
\end{bmatrix}

And

\begin{bmatrix}
z^{-1}& 0 \\
0 & z 
\end{bmatrix}

I know the matrix that make them conjugate is this one:

\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1  \\
-1 & 0 
\end{bmatrix}

but I do not know the calculations that lead us to this matrix, could anyone show me the calculations please?

Comment: It would be good for you to state the definition of conjugate matrices

Comment: For this specific one it is obvious, since we just need to 'flip' the values...

Comment: is it a memorized matrix @Trebor

Comment: @NazimJ  A,B are conjugate matrices iff $ABA^{-1} = B$

Comment: It is not. But you should be able to know that after some practice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, these two matrices are always conjugate:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
u & 0 \\
0 & v 
\end{bmatrix},
\qquad
\begin{bmatrix}
v & 0 \\
0 & u 
\end{bmatrix}
$$
and any invertible matrix of the form below conjugates them:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & b \\
c & 0 
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Indeed,
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
a & b \\
c & d 
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
u & 0 \\
0 & v 
\end{bmatrix}
-
\begin{bmatrix}
v & 0 \\
0 & u 
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
a & b \\
c & d 
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
a (u - v) & 0 \\
0 & d (u - v)
\end{bmatrix}
$$
which gives $a=0, d=0$ if $u\ne v$.

Recall that two matrices $A$ and $B$ are conjugate iff there is an invertible matrix $P$ such that $PAP^{-1}=B$, or equivalently $PA-BP=0$.